# async waterfall callback was already called error in nodejs

Tags: node.js, callback, waterfall

I am newbee to nodejs. I have been scratching my head for long time on why below code throwing error.I found some similar in stack overflow, but couldn't get help in finding the bug.

```
var albums_coll,photos_coll;    
    async.waterfall([
      function(cb){
        MongoClient.connect(url,
         (err,dbase)=>{
          if(err) {
            console.log('bad');
            process.exit(-1);
          }
          console.log("I have a connection!");
          db=dbase;
          cb(null);
        }
        );
      },

      function(cb){
        db.collection("albums",cb);
      },

      function(album_obj,cb){
        albums_coll = album_obj;
      db.collection("photos",cb);
    },

    function(photos_obj,cb){
      photos_coll = photos_obj;
      cb(null);

    },

    function(cb){
      albums_coll.InsertOne(a1,cb);
    },
    function(inserted_doc,cb){
      console.log("I have Inserted a document!!");
      console.log(inserted_doc);
      cb(null);
    }
    ],
    function(err,results){
      console.log("Done!!!");
      console.log(err);
      console.log(results);
      db.close();
    });
```

Please suggest!!

the following is the error its showing.

```
I have a connection!
C:\Users\thathine\NodeLive\Chapter08\mongotest\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongo_client.js:433
          throw err
          ^

Error: Callback was already called.
    at C:\Users\thathine\NodeLive\Chapter08\mongotest\node_modules\async\dist\async.js:903:32
    at Db.collection (C:\Users\thathine\NodeLive\Chapter08\mongotest\node_modules\mongodb\lib\db.js:466:27)
      .
      .           
      .
```

Comment: what is the value of albums_coll in second last callback method? i dont think it is defined anywhere

Answer (score 0):

The `callback()` function you are passing into the `db.collection()` function is being called **twice**. The first time this happens is inside the **MongoDB library** while invoking `db.collection()`. It is happening in the following block - I added a comment pointing to **line 466** as shown in the stack:

```
if(options == null || !options.strict) {
    try {
      var collection = new Collection(this, this.s.topology, this.s.databaseName, name, this.s.pkFactory, options);
      if(callback) callback(null, collection);
      return collection;
    } catch(err) {
      // if(err instanceof MongoError && callback) return callback(err);
      if(callback) return callback(err);  // <-- Line 466 - first time callback is called
      throw err;
    }
  }
```

The second time it gets called, is by the **async library when it needs to determine if it has to execute the next task in the array or invoke the final callback**; by then, the callback is already null. The error you're seeing is being raised in the `onlyOnce()` function that is part of the **async library**:

```
function onlyOnce(fn) {
    return function() {
        if (fn === null) throw new Error("Callback was already called.");
        var callFn = fn;
        fn = null;
        callFn.apply(this, arguments);
    };
}
```

So the following code will raise the error:

```
async.waterfall([
    function(callback) {
        MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/test', (error, db) => {
            if (error) {
                console.error(error);
                process.exit(-1);
            }
            callback(null, db);
        });
    },
    function(db, callback) {
        console.log('Querying albums collection...');

        // This will cause the exception
        db.collection('albums', callback);
    },
    function(db, albums, callback) {
        console.log('Got albums...');
        console.log('Querying photos collection...');

        db.collection('photos', (error, photos) => {
            if (error) {
                return callback(error);
            }

            callback(null, db, albums, photos);
        });
    },
    function(db, albums, photos, callback) {
        console.log('Got photos...');

        callback(null, 'DONE');
    }
], function (error, results) {
    console.error(error);
    console.log(results);

    process.exit(0);
});
```

While this version of the code will execute as expected:

```
async.waterfall([
    function(callback) {
        MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/test', (error, db) => {
            if (error) {
                console.error(error);
                process.exit(-1);
            }
            callback(null, db);
        });
    },
    function(db, callback) {
        console.log('Querying albums collection...');

        db.collection('albums', (error, albums) => {
            if (error) {
                return callback(error);
            }

            callback(null, db, albums);
        });
    },
    function(db, albums, callback) {
        console.log('Got albums...');
        console.log('Querying photos collection...');

        db.collection('photos', (error, photos) => {
            if (error) {
                return callback(error);
            }

            callback(null, db, albums, photos);
        });
    },
    function(db, albums, photos, callback) {
        console.log('Got photos...');

        callback(null, 'DONE');
    }
], function (error, results) {
    console.error(error);
    console.log(results);

    process.exit(0);
});
/* Output:
Querying albums collection...
Got albums...
Querying photos collection...
Got photos...
null
DONE
*/
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi @mscheker Thanks for your quick response. I really appreciate your work. After some careful observation again, i found that the error is because of `albums_coll.InsertOne(a1,cb);` I had a typo. the function inserOne(a1,cb) worked correctly instead. After i corrected the typo., then my  above code worked well.